# Why does my linked list not not print out in proper order?

Tags: linked-list

the output for this is incorrect. The name of the second train appears instead of the first and the name of the first train is lost altogether. Where is the logical fault? Also, what is the purpose of the root?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
struct trainset {
    char name[50];
    int price;
    struct trainset *next;
};

void show_list(struct trainset *list);

int main (void){

    struct trainset *root;
    root = (struct trainset *)malloc(sizeof(struct trainset));      
    strncpy(root ->name, " ", 50);
    root ->price = 0;
    root ->next = 0;

    struct trainset *first_train;
    first_train = (struct trainset *) malloc(sizeof(struct trainset)); 
    root ->next = first_train;
    strncpy(first_train->name, "Fantasy Train Set", 50);
    first_train->price = 129;
    first_train->next = NULL;

    struct trainset *second_train;
    second_train = (struct trainset *)malloc(sizeof(struct trainset));
    first_train->next = second_train;
    strncpy(first_train->name, "Uncle Bobs train set", 50);
    second_train ->price = 69;
    second_train ->next = NULL;

    struct trainset *third_train;
    third_train = (struct trainset *)malloc(sizeof(struct trainset));
    second_train->next = third_train;
    strncpy(third_train ->name, "Budha Bread Train", 50);
    third_train ->price = 169;
    third_train ->next = NULL;

    show_list(first_train);
    return 0;
}

void show_list(struct trainset *list)
{
    while(list->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("train set name: %s, Train price: %d\n", list->name, list->price);
        list = list->next;
    }
    printf("train set name: %s, train price: %d", list->name, list->price);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well here's where the name is going:

```
strncpy(first_train->name, "Fantasy Train Set", 50);
...
strncpy(first_train->name, "Uncle Bobs train set", 50);
```

As to what root is for... it's your code, who knows. You don't need a root node, you just need to record what the first node is.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be rewriting the first_train->name.

```
 23     strncpy(first_train->name, "Fantasy Train Set", 50);  // see here
 24     first_train->price = 129;
 25     first_train->next = NULL;
 26     struct trainset *second_train;
 27     second_train = (struct trainset *)malloc(sizeof(struct trainset));
 28     first_train->next = second_train;
 29     strncpy(first_train->name, "Uncle Bobs train set", 50);   // and here
```

You should have functions and procedures to do the insertion and creation operations, and I don't know why you have an empty root node, you don't need to do that, your root pointer can pint to the first_train node.

You should do something like:

```
list* create(int value) {
    node = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    node->value = value;
    node->next = NULL;
}

list* insert(int value, list* root) {
    if (!root) {
        return create(value);
    }
    list* aux = root;
    while(aux->next) {
        aux = aux->next;
    }
    aux->next = create(value);
    return root;
}
```

Also, on your loop condition you have:

```
while(list->next != NULL)
```

You can rewrite it like this and this way you avoid to print the last element out of the loop:

```
while(list){ ... }
```

Hope this helps